# My theme not supporting Page Builder by SiteOrigin

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Recently i converted a HTML template to WP theme. It functioning good but the  Page Builder by SiteOrigin plugin is not functioning i mean stylish etc. 
How can i make my theme to support this plugin ?
Is these bootstrap themes support this plugin ?
please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Most page builder plugins operate by taking over the_content() function in WordPress. Is your theme utilizing that function on your single post/page templates?

While I can't help with SiteOrigin's page builder, I am on a team that released [the FastLine Page Builder](http://themes.fastlinemedia.com). If you're not able to get SiteOrigin's builder working, give ours a try. We would be more than happy to continue helping you troubleshoot!